# Am I doing something wrong in this modal popup

Tags: jquery

Need Help Need help with modal pop up.  I am new to this and learning.  Pop is not working for some reason.  Getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function.

I know i'm doing something wrong.  Can you please suggest and how to fix

---

```
 <!-- popup code start here -->
<div class="modal fade" id="mypop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>We are unable to locate your device.</h4>
        <h4>Please select your country and language.</h4>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 no_padding">
                <div class="no_padding">
            <label>My Country:</label>
            <select name="countries_popup" id="countries_popup" class="selectBox">
            <option selected="selected">Choose country</option>
                <option>United Kingdom</option>

            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 no_padding">
                <div class="no_padding">
            <label>My language:</label>
            <select name="language_popup" id="language_popup" class="selectBox">
            <option selected="selected">Choose language</option>

                <option>United Kingdom</option>

            </select>
            </div>
            </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-6 gonext">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- popup code end here -->

$(window).load(function(){ 
console.log("popup")
$("#mypop").modal();

});
```

Comment: Have you included the library for the `.modal()` function?

Comment: try $("#mypop").dialog(); instead of modal(). here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vrqdsq12/

Comment: Jay, I am using bootstrap.min.js and jquery.js.  From reading, it includes the .modal() function.

Comment: Hey Sushil, dialog() works but none of the css is getting applied.

Comment: @ron include jqueryui css. the fiddle is using a different css

Comment: here.. try this @ron  http://jsfiddle.net/vrqdsq12/1/

Comment: I've posted my solution as an answer @ron please mark it as a solution if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into a generic page layout (using CDNs for jQuery & bootstrap), everything seems to work.  You have to be sure to include both jQuery and bootstrap, before performing any functions related to those libraries.  I generally include libraries and scripts at the end of the page body, however you can wrap your launch code in $(document).ready(function(){...}); if you wish.

```
<html lang="en" class="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ron Help</title>
  <meta name="description" content="app, web app, responsive, admin dashboard, admin, flat, flat ui, ui kit, off screen nav" />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body class="">

<div class="modal fade" id="mypop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>We are unable to locate your device.</h4>
        <h4>Please select your country and language.</h4>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 no_padding">
                <div class="no_padding">
            <label>My Country:</label>
            <select name="countries_popup" id="countries_popup" class="selectBox">
            <option selected="selected">Choose country</option>
                <option>Austria</option>
                <option>United Kingdom</option>
                <option>Ireland</option>
                <option>Romania</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 no_padding">
                <div class="no_padding">
            <label>My language:</label>
            <select name="language_popup" id="language_popup" class="selectBox">
            <option selected="selected">Choose language</option>
                <option>Austria</option>
                <option>United Kingdom</option>
                <option>Ireland</option>
                <option>Romania</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-6 gonext">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){ 
  console.log("popup")
  $("#mypop").modal();

       $('.gonext').click(function(){
            var countriesValue = $('select#countries_popup option:selected').val();
           var languageValue = $('select#language_popup option:selected').val();



           $('#countries option').filter(function() { 
                  return ($(this).text() == countriesValue);

              }).prop('selected', true);
           $('#countries option,#language option').prop('disabled', true);
           $('#language option').filter(function() { 
                  return ($(this).text() == languageValue); 
              }).prop('selected', true);


          $('.modal-open #mypop,.modal-backdrop.fade.in').hide();
          $('body').removeClass('modal-open');

       });
  });
</script>
</body>    
</html>
```

It should be safe to exclude the window.load() while the script is after the body content.

Answer (score 0):

since you're using bootstrap you need to include the `css` and `js` file refrerences.

include the following after you have included your `jquery` tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

here's a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vrqdsq12/1/) for the same.